# Views: Filter results by current logged-in user

Tags: drupal-views

I'm trying to create a view to show a list of past events that were attended by the user that's currently logged in.

Could anyone advise on the filter criteria needed to do this?

**Fields**

> Event Title
>
> Event End date

**Filter criteria**

> Status = attended
>
> ???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it!

To limit views results to the current user, you want to:

1. **Create a relationship**

> Go to Advanced > Relationships > Add 'CiviCRM Contacts: Drupal ID'

2. **Add the filter criteria**

> User: Current (Yes)
>
> On the Relationship dropdown, select Drupal User